# Why does std::ios_base::failure have two inheritance diagrams and what is the difference?

Tags: c++, exception

According to [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/failure), `std::ios_base::failure` has two inheritance hierarchies:

[image]

**Question**

Why and what is the difference?

**Background**

Using g++ 4.7.1 I ran into this error and so far I know that it is because of the first inheritance hierarchy:

> error: 'const class std::ios_base::failure' has no member named 'code'

**UPDATE**

With gcc, `ios_base::failure` still inherits from `exception` even in C++11 mode. Quote from [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.200x):

> ios_base::failure is not derived from system_error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because [std::system_error](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/system_error) was introduced in C++11. `std::ios_base::failure` derived directly from `std::exception` before.

Since the [code()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/system_error/code) method is a member of `std::system_error`, `std::ios_base::failure` does not expose it in environments that do not support C++11.

Comment: You can find it in 27.5.3.1.1 of [C++11](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) standard

Comment: Ah, makes sense, I'm slightly surprised g++ 4.7.1 hasn't implemented it yet.

Comment: @JesseGood: And you compiled with `-std=c++11`?

Comment: @Xeo: Yes I have, I also [peeked in the header](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/latest-doxygen/a01278_source.html) and as far I can tell it is unimplemented (unless Im missing something).

Comment: It seems to be implemented now in [libstdc++](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57953) 4.8.1.